# How to add html5smartimage inside a custom widget?(AEM 5.6.1)

Tags: image, extjs, aem

I am trying to add a html5smartimage in a multifield using ExtJS. The label shows up but I am not able to add images. The code I am using is as below.

```
this.image=new CQ.html5.form.SmartImage({
        fieldLabel : "Image",
        allowBlank : false,
        allowUpload:"{Boolean}false",
        border:"{Boolean}true",
        cropParameter:"",
        ddGroups:"[media]",
        disableInfo:"{Boolean}true",
        disableZoom:"{Boolean}true",
        fileNameParameter:"",
        fileReferenceParameter:"./image/fileReference",
        height:"{Long}500",
        mapParameter:"",
        name:"file",
        requestSuffix:"",
        rotateParameter:"",
        title:"Image",
        listeners : {
            change : {
                scope : this,
                fn : this.updateHidden
            },
            dialogclose : {
                scope : this,
                fn : this.updateHidden
            }
        }
    });
```

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: did you try this link: http://experience-aem.blogspot.in/2013/12/aem-cq-56-adding-images-in-multifield.html and this http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2014/04/aem-cq-56-slide-show-component.html and this http://experience-aem.blogspot.in/2015/06/aem-61-classic-ui-nested-composite-multifield-panel.html. This site has numerous examples for custom multifields with images

Comment: Thank you @SaravanaPrakash. This woudn't work for me because I want the image to be part of a custom widget which has several other fields.

Comment: These examples support image with other fields as well.